# Customize keychain alert actions

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I'm wondering if customization of the keychain alert is possible? Below you can find the image:

[image]

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

When the authentication with FaceID/TouchID fails and pops above shown alert, I want user to tap Enter Passcode and show my custom Application Passcode UI, instead of device passcode (system ui). Basically, I want to customize the fallback action.

**Context:**
I know it is possible with using `LAContext`, however due to the reasons that we can bypass it, I don't feel comfortable in implementing that, so I chose Keychain accessControlFlags.

**Snapshot code, what I currently have:**

```
func data(forAccount account: String, service: String, accessGroup: String?) throws -> Data? {
    guard let accessControl = createAccessControl(with: .userPresence) else { return nil }
    var query = self.query(forAccount: account, service: service, accessGroup: accessGroup)

    var authContext = LAContext()
    authContext.localizedFallbackTitle = "Enter Passcode"
    authContext.localizedCancelTitle = "Cancel"

    query[KeychainConstants.matchLimit] = KeychainConstants.matchLimitOne
    query[KeychainConstants.returnData] = kCFBooleanTrue
    query[KeychainConstants.authenticationContext] = authContext
    query[KeychainConstants.accessControl] = accessControl

    var result: AnyObject?
    let status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &result) {
        securityItemManager.copyMatching(query, result: UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
    }

    if let error = error(fromStatus: status), error != .itemNotFound  {
        throw error
    }
    guard result != nil else { return nil }
    guard let resultData = result as? Data else { throw AccessError.invalidQueryResult }
    return resultData
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that you need to use the LAContext fallback in order to do it. When presenting this view, users will always have the possibility to use biometry or cancel.

Comment: @iDev thanks for reply. How can I use LAContext fallback in this case can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I will add a answer with more description

Answer (score 1):

The only customization you can do is change the dialog buttons labels. You can do this using the following:

```
 let context = LAContext()

 context.localizedFallbackTitle = ""
 context.localizedCancelTitle = "Manual connection"
```

By setting the `localizedFallbackTitle` property to an empty string removes the fallback button (enter password).

Unfortunately, there is no "delegate" kind of callback for this dialog. You need to manage the user interaction using errors. Therefore, `LAError.userCancel` is triggered when user has pressed the cancel button and `LAError.userFallback` is triggered when the fallback button has been pressed.

Here's an example:

```
let context = LAContext()
context.localizedFallbackTitle = "Facebook"
context.localizedCancelTitle = "Web Connection"

[...]

context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
                       localizedReason: "My reason") { (success, errorOrNil) in

if let error = errorOrNil {

   if success {

      // The evaluation succeeded

   } else {

      if let error = errorOrNil {

         switch error {
             case .userCancel: 

                 // Execute the custom actions you want to do. Here it would be
                 // to start a web login process.
                 self.webLogin()

             case .userFallback: 

                self.fabebookAuthentication() 

             default: 
                 // Other error thrown by the framework.
         }
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That's sad that they haven't yet implemented the callback. I know that it is possible with evaluatePolicy :)